# use of events between python threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm starting to learn writing multithreaded python code. In particular I'm trying to use events between thread. For some reason the code below is not working and I can't find out why.
Do you have any suggestion?
Thank you in advance!

```
import threading
import time

e1 = threading.Event()

def counting_thread():
    x=0
    while 1:
        print(x)
        if x==5:
            e1.set
        x=x+1
        if x==11:
            x=0
        time.sleep(1)

def speaking_thread():
    while not e1.wait():
        print('You just said five!')

t1 = threading.Thread(target=counting_thread)
t1.start()

t2 = threading.Thread(target=speaking_thread)
t2.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually call the `set` method.

```
    if x==5:
        e1.set()
```